# Is there any pseudorandom number generator using only cyclic shifts?

Tags: algorithm, random, theory

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) Wikipedia article, for example, presents a simple RNG using only xor and shift:

```
/* The state word must be initialized to non-zero */
uint32_t xorshift32(uint32_t state[static 1])
{
    /* Algorithm "xor" from p. 4 of Marsaglia, "Xorshift RNGs" */
    uint32_t x = state[0];
    x ^= x << 13;
    x ^= x >> 17;
    x ^= x << 5;
    state[0] = x;
    return x;
}
```

The shift operations used there, though, fill removed bits with 0. Assuming the only operations available are cyclic shifts and xor, is it possible to implement an equally simple, long-cycle RNG? The code above will not work because it cycles after a few iterations, which is expected since it was designed for non-cyclic shifts.

Comment: You may look at LFSRs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Comment: the LFSRs I've seen never use rotation, only shifting. But it's hard to tell there aren't any for sure. Note C doesn't have operators for rotating bits, so what's the usecase? Want to implement it in assembly?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I've removed the C tag.

Comment: I don't see a reason for a downvote! Except maybe it would be better to also explain what problem is to be solved? I don't get it, but definitely didn't downvote.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I'm certain I explained what the problem to be solved clearly and succinctly, and anything else would be redundant. Just thinking: downvotes should be visible, require justifications and open for contestation, with possible punishments. That'd be beautiful.

Comment: No, you just asked "is there xyz" without even explaining why you think you need it. This might still be interesting just out of curiosity, but definitely limits the possibilities to help -- cause sometimes there is a better way than the one you initially though of.

Comment: My gut feeling would be that shifts are better because they have both direction and shift amount, whereas rotations just have rotation amount.

Comment: Empirically, with the shifts replaced by rotations, the state seems to collapse to all-zeros after at most NBITS-1 iterations. I haven't proved it though.

Comment: @IanAbbott that is my experience too. I was wondering if different values or slightly different algorithms could avoid that collapse.

Comment: Correction: the state collapses to all-zeroes after at most NBITS iterations. I think it is easy to show that for a single rotation, and shouldn't be that much harder to show for multiple rotations.

Comment: Isn't Xoroshiro+128 such a RNG? XOR/rotate/shift/rotate operations. http://vigna.di.unimi.it/xorshift/xoroshiro128plus.c

Comment: @MaiaVictor honestly, it's not that I care very much. People tend to like seeing the motivation (the *source* of the problem) as well, things like XY-problems happen. I just tried to find a possible explanation for the downvote. Then please don't whine about it and move on ...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the cycle will be at most 2*n if using n bits, i.e. you cannot get long cycles with few bits.

The reason is that after **at most** `n` operations the rotations are back to the origin, and thus the result is `state_n=state_0^someThing` (since rotation and xor can be combined). And after n more we get back to state_0. Note that xoroshiro+128 has one shift as well.